# Symfony2: Routing ignores port in URL

Tags: php, http, symfony

I'm trying to run a Symfony2 based web app under port 8080 instead of port 80. Now I've noticed that all absolute routes lack the port sepcification in the URL. This is also true for redirects, which try to redirect to port 80 as well.
Also, when using url('') in the twig templates, no port is included.

What I've tried up to now is setting the framework.router.http_port setting, which didn't do anything. Then I tried to manually create a RequestContext and pass it to the router during bundle bootup, also to no avail. This is the code I've tried:

```
$router = $this->container->get('router');
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
    list($host, $port) = explode(':', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

    $context = new RequestContext(
            '',
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'],
            $host,
            (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])?'http':'https'),
            $port
    );
    $router->setContext($context);
}
```

Comment: Routes should be normally not care about the port, because that's part of the host, not the path. For redirects, this might be a flaw of the redirect implementation. However it does support any valid URI (including with ports) in it's inner: https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/blob/master/RedirectResponse.php

Comment: I found the problem. I'm developing on a VBox machine confiured with port forwarding from my localhost:8080 to the VBox port 80. Symfony routing apparently relies on the SERVER_PORT global instead of what's specified in the request URI.
So the solution is to either reconfigure nginx to set 8080 as the SERVER_PORT, or to really let it run on port 8080.

Comment: That explains it, indeed. That port forwarding is something like a proxy. Symfony2 can deal with that, too, next to server configuration, you should be able to solve this with symfony configuration as well, but I don't know exactly how this works. Look for transparent proxy/load balancer setups. And it would be great if you can compile an answer out of this.

Answer (score 1):

From the OP:

> I'm developing on a VBox machine confiured with port forwarding from
>   my localhost:8080 to the VBox port 80. Symfony routing apparently
>   relies on the SERVER_PORT global instead of what's specified in the
>   request URI. So the solution is to either reconfigure nginx to set
>   8080 as the SERVER_PORT, or to really let it run on port 8080.